# How can i plot a signal from 0 to Fs/2 in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I read a sound in matlab.

```
[y,Fs]=audioread('sound_noisy.wav');
magnitude=abs((fft(y)));
```

Now, how can i plot this magnitude from 0 to Fs/2 in matlab?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the `plot` function? What is the difficulty?

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I want to know how can i plot signal in frequency domain.

Comment: If you want to plot `magnitude` just say `plot(magnitude)`. If you want to know what the x-axis values are, that is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4364823/7328782 or for MATLAB syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41240420/7328782

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I obtain the frequencies of each value in an FFT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-do-i-obtain-the-frequencies-of-each-value-in-an-fft)

Answer (score 0):

```
f = linspace(0, Fs/2, length(magnitude)/2)
plot(f, magnitude(1:half))
```